# How can I get my compiled array from ng-options in a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I have a custom directive which I am decorating a `<select ng-options="">` with as such...

```
<select custom ng-model="selected" ng-options="o for o in values">
```

with `custom` as my directive and `values` being a simple array. Here is my implementation...

```
<select custom ng-model="selected" ng-options="o for o in values">
    <option value selected>uhh?</option>
</select>
```

---

```
app.directive('custom', [function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // how can I get my array of values here?
        }
    }
}])
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.values = ['er', 'um', 'eh'];
}])
```

Within my `link` I can see it as such

```
console.log(attrs.ngOptions);
```

Which, in this case, logs out the literal `"o for o in values"`. Can I somehow parse or compile this within my `link` to get the array? I see I can grab it if I do something like `scope.$parent.values`, but this seems unnecessary and I would need to know the name of `"values"`. I can probably get it through some hacky feeling string manipulation to target it, but I am hoping there is a more intuitive way.

hacky e.g.

```
var array = attrs.ngOptions.split(' ').pop(); // "values"

console.log(scope.$parent[array]);
```

Side note - constricted to AngularJS 1.2.x for this example

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/t1143q96/) - example

Comment: You could set another attribute to your directive, `my-array={{values}}`, and get this value with `attrs.myArray`.

Comment: You could just do something like `<select custom="values" ...>`. It's not very DRY, yes. The problem is that the expression of `ng-options` is a microsyntax of that directive. You could definitely use regex to extract `values` out of it (this is what `ngOptions` does under the covers), then `$parse(values)(scope)` to get the values...  but parsing another directive's microsyntax seems somewhat fragile and a bit of an overkill

Comment: Agreed on both suggestions. I was hoping for a way to scrape these values in my JS to keep the markup as minimal as possible. If you post a clear answer with this I'll gladly accept if we can't get my ideal solution. It is what it is!

Comment: Sorry, I  deleted that comment just after posting. It seems that ngOptions does not define a controller, and ngModel does not expose options provided by this directive, so there is no easy way to get it. What do you want to do with this options?

Comment: No worries! I want to default an option if one does not supply the default `<option>` tag. I wanted to compare the length of the options array to the html nodes and if not matched, default a value. Couldn't think of a better way quite yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Angular v1.4, neither `select` nor `ngOptions` directives provide an API to get the array of items that results in `<option>`s, so we are only left with 2 choices - 1) pass the `values` array explicitly to `custom` directive as an attribute value, or 2) derive it from the micro-syntax of `ng-options`.

With **#1** - the approach is straightforward.

With **#2** - we would need to parse the microsyntax, for example with `RegExp`. This is fragile, since the micro-syntax may change in the future.

We could use Angular's own regex expression (see [src v1.4.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L218)) to parse this syntax:

```
var NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+disable\s+when\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?$/;
```

(the 8th group matches the items)

Or, we could make it a simpler regex, perhaps even stabler, for example:

```
/^.*\s+in\s+(\S+)[\s\S]*$/
```

At any rate, the directive would look like so:

```
app.directive('custom', function($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var optionsExp = attrs.ngOptions;

      var match = optionsExp.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP);

      var valuesExp = match[8];

      var valuesFn = $parse(valuesExp);

      var values = valuesFn(scope.$parent);

      // or simpler: 
      // var values = $parse(match[8])(scope.$parent);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer this. I'll likely go the straightfoward route and accept that as an answer, but I'm curious about the manual way. I tried this, and referenced 1.4.3 just to see, but can't quite get it. Can you check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oo46w96e/) out to see what I mean? Thanks

Comment: @salniro, ah... forgot that the directive has an isolate scope - we'd need to use `scope.$parent` instead - fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Look the fiddle below.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4e48s4o/)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select custom ng-model="selected" ng-options="o for o in values">
        <option value selected>uhh?</option>
    </select>
</div>


var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('custom', [function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.values)
        }
    }
}])
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.values = ['er', 'um', 'eh'];
}])
```

Comment: JSFiddle 404 and `undefined`. My scope is isolated and I'd need to know the array name of `values`, which I'd prefer to find a generic solution so this could be named anything

Comment: Look above.Click on it..it's autjorization issue with fiddler

& check values in console.

Comment: And let me kame it for isolated scope for you.

Comment: Hi @sal niro ,
 have a look of this directive if you want to isolate the scope & wants all the things in link method to manipulate.

http://jsfiddle.net/zfxrr7wu/

Comment: @ sal niro ,did you staisfied or you can explain it better what you trying to achive..?

Comment: hey I have not yet found a good way to do so, I'd prefer not to decorate my select further with another attributive. I was hoping there was a way to `$compile` my ngOptions expression. I'll update this if I find a clever way, Thanks!