# AngularJS select doesn't error when model value not in options

Tags: angularjs, validation, html-select

Angular 1.4.8.

I have this markup for 2-letter US state codes:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.licenseState.$invalid }">
    <label for="licenseState" class="control-label">License State</label>
    <select name="licenseState" id="licenseState" class="form-control" required
            ng-model="ctrl.student.License.State"
            ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in ctrl.licenseFormats">
    </select>
</div>
```

This properly gives me an error when the model value is loaded as blank.

[image]

However, when the model value is loaded as a value not in the list (bad data), it does not error.

[image]

The situation baffles me considering the result is misinformation at all levels. User sees a blank value which appears to be valid (despite `required` attribute). Model sees a different value from user which appears to be valid even though it's absent from the valid values list.

Am I missing something? Is there a proper (canonical angular) way to make this trigger a form validation error?

---

**Update**

Based on the answer from @paul147, I ended up with this reusable directive for validating a model value against a list.

```
m.directive('validValues', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            validValues: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            var values = angular.isArray(scope.validValues)
                ? scope.validValues
                : Object.keys(scope.validValues);
            ngModel.$validators.validValues = function (modelValue) {
                return values.indexOf(modelValue) !== -1;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Example usage:

```
<select name="licenseState" required valid-values="ctrl.licenseFormats"
        ng-model="ctrl.student.License.State"
        ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in ctrl.licenseFormats">
</select>
```

I briefly explored getting the options directly from the select element, but ngOptions puts the values in a custom format. F.ex `string:AL` (which is actually a lookup key) for the value of `AL`. Further discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014428/how-can-i-get-my-compiled-array-from-ng-options-in-a-custom-directive). Ultimately, the directive is more reusable with less effort if I just do it as above with the redundant declaration of valid values (`ctrl.licenseFormats` in this case).

Comment: Well, as you're saying, it's a bad idea. This is a bug in your code, that you should just prevent. If you decide that it's best to set the licenseState to null if it's not one of the valid keys, then do it. But angular won't do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, my brain read "bad idea" instead of "bad data". But still, the data is invalid, and you need to avoid that. The validator tests that the model is not null. And it's not. So there is no reason for the validator to display an error. **You** are saying angular that it should select the value licensePlate, although licensePlate is not one of the selectable options. That's a bug in your code. Angular tries to compensate by adding an option for the value that must be selected.

Comment: I can't avoid bad data that is already a matter of record. The whole reason to use a `select` is to limit the valid options. Hence, a required validator approving a value which is not actually a valid option is... unexpected. And what is the purpose of a validator which requires me to pre-validate the data?

Comment: The validator validates that the model value is not null. And it is not null. A validator validates what the user enters or select. It doesn't validate that your model makes sense. It doesn't make sense. Just test that licensePlate is one of the valid values, and set it to null if it's not, since that's what you want.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting "licensePlate". I don't think you actually read the question. I think you just want to argue philosophy when I asked for a means to trigger an ng-form validation error in a specific case.

Comment: OK. licenseState. As I said several times: if you want the **required** validation to fail, the model must be null (or undefined). As simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do to trigger errors on the ngModel directive is to add a custom validator to the ngModel's $validators.

The ngModel's value is passed through the $validators whenever it changes, and an error is raised if the validator returns false.

An example implementation is to add a custom directive to the model's element, and define the validator inside that directive:

Here's a plunkr with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/m6OygVR2GyMOXTTVTuhf?p=preview

```
// markup
<select name="licenseState" id="licenseState" class="form-control" required
  ng-model="student.License.State"
  ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in licenseFormats"
  check-state
  license-formats="licenseFormats">

// in the controller
$scope.licenseFormats = {
  'OR': 'Oregon', 
  'WA': 'Washington', 
};     

// the directive
app.directive('checkState', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      licenseFormats: '='
    }, 
    restrict: 'A', 
    require: 'ngModel', 
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

      // defining the validator here
      ngModel.$validators.state = function(modelValue) {
        return Object.keys(scope.licenseFormats).indexOf(modelValue) > -1;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to pull the valid values from the options which were already specified on the select?

Comment: the select and directive are using the same set of defined values, $scope,licenseFormats, it's passing it to both so they'll always be tied together.

Comment: Found the answer to my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014428/how-can-i-get-my-compiled-array-from-ng-options-in-a-custom-directive). Passing the same values again appears most straight-forward, albeit redundant.

Comment: Any good workarounds for AngularJS 1.2? There is no ngModel.$validators property.